# Inject Bean failed by using JSR annotation

Tags: java, spring

See my code below:

```
Point.jave:    
package org.dxc.java.technology.part20;

public class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}


Circle.java:
package org.dxc.java.technology.part20;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class Circle implements IShape{
    private Point center;

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    @Resource(name="point1")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("X: " + center.getX() + ", Y: " + center.getY());
    }
}
```

spring_part20.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="circle" class="org.dxc.java.technology.part20.Circle">

    </bean>

    <bean id="point1" class="org.dxc.java.technology.part20.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"></property>
        <property name="y" value="0"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

when I get Circle bean and call draw method like this:

```
public class Drive {

    static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ConfigurationFiles/spring_part20.xml"); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
    }
    static void test1()
    {
        IShape shape = (IShape)context.getBean("circle");
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

I got NullPointerException as below:

```
Apr 13, 2017 8:44:42 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@497470ed: startup date [Thu Apr 13 08:44:42 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 13, 2017 8:44:42 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ConfigurationFiles/spring_part20.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.dxc.java.technology.part20.Circle.draw(Circle.java:19)
    at org.dxc.java.technology.part20.Drive.test1(Drive.java:16)
    at org.dxc.java.technology.part20.Drive.main(Drive.java:10)
```

so, does anyone can tell me what's the problem and how to fix it if I want to use JSR annotation to inject bean.

Comment: how about `@Resource(name="point1") private Point center;` ?

Comment: also do you have the `<context:component-scan base-package="org.dxc.java.technology.part20" />`

Comment: thanks Scary Wombat, I do missed the <context>tag in configuration file, and also, I change the <beans> tag like this: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> it works now for me